# MobileFirst 8.0 Push Notification REST API Access token

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, firebase-cloud-messaging

For Sending the notification using REST API's we have to generate access token first and its expiration time 1 hour.

So my question is for Production server every 1 hour we have to generate access token to use this API? Is there any other way to increase this expiration time or bypass this using any admin url or any other thing?

Can any one help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the access token expiration time for a confidential client is set to 1 hour, and cannot be changed or bypassed.

Please submit feature requests here: mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/help

Comment: Thanx I will do that. So basically now for production applications also we have to generate Access token in every 1 hour right?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's product or not, if you're using a confidential client (which seems like you are since you want to use the REST API), the expiration time is 1 hour.

Comment: Ok thanx a lot.

Comment: Apart from confidential client, is there any other type of client? Directly is there any other way to send notification?

Comment: Depends on your intent, always to all devices or to a list of specific devices... the more complex your scenario becomes, you'll need to use APIs. If all you need is to send push to a specific tag or only to android or only to iOS or to all devices, you can explore using the push page in the console (your-app > push).

Comment: Yah using API only. My intent its just send notification using REST API, but this new concept of access token is the problem as have to generate new token every hour. So for that any other way to do this?

Comment: Hello @Suhas , just a question, what prevents you to create a access token in front to sending the MFP Push? 
I had more or less the same challenge, I solved this by build a reusable self registering module. My sample implementation is related to Node.JS, but maybe it helps. Here is the link to a blog and there you can find the link to the github project: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/10/18/using-mff-8-push-service-rest-api-in-a-nodejs-based-server/